# Какой правильный uploaddir openserver php?

Tags: php, openserver

сделал форму добавления товаров. И загрузку изображений
Загрузку в папке uploads/ и такой простой скрит

```
$uploaddir =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {

}
```

Скрипт отрабатывает и загружает и файл и в базе данных такой путь
C:/OSPanel/domains/site/uploads/s9.jpg
Но при выводе у меня такой src для img

```
<img src="C:/OSPanel/domains/rahim/uploads/s1.jpg" alt="">
```

И такая ошибка в консоле

```
Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/OSPanel/domains/rahim/uploads/s7.jpg
```

Comment: в базу записывайте так: uploads/s1.jpg.

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(/uploads/s8.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\OSPanel\domains\rahim\check.php on line 22

Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\OSPanel\userdata\temp\phpC792.tmp' to '/uploads/s8.jpg' in C:\OSPanel\domains\rahim\check.php on line 22
Добавить еще продукт

Такая ошибка если

Comment: Нет. Переносите файл вы правильно. В базу данных нужно записывать `uploads/s1.jpg`

Comment: Надо было точку ставить))
$uploaddir =  './uploads/';